# How to find the focal and the pp parameter in opencv for a smartphone video?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, visual-odometry

Hello I want to developp a Visual odometry app for Smartphone. I already created a working pipeline using kitty dataset. Now I wasn't able to make it work with a video I took using my smartphone (Galaxy S22+). I need the intrinsic parameters which are pp and focal. I tried these values: pp=(960, 540) (the video I took is 1080x1920 pix), and focal=23000 since the sensor in normally 1um and the focal 23 mm. Please help me.

Comment: You need to do `camera calibration` in order to get the focal parameters (matrix) of a camera as every camera is a bit different. Follow this tutorial to find out more: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d94/tutorial_camera_calibration.html

Comment: your focal distance is implausible. **do not** calculate with "35mm-equivalent" values ("23 mm"). those are wrong. you also need to know the sensor resolution, not the resolution of any video mode. for the video mode, you also need to know how it was binned and cropped, or even resampled. EIS will do arbitrary things. -- @DimitarVeljanovski you're missing the part where this question calculates the intrinsics from other values, which is okay to do.

Comment: @DimitarVeljanovski For the phone I think the distortions are already removed from the video. Or is it separate things? I forgot I'm using python btw

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry I didn't understand this part 'implausible' what do you mean by that? And also the resolution part do you have an example in mind? Thankyou btw

Comment: please dig up authoritative information on that device's camera sensor.